# Redirect WordPress URLs to parent page without changing URL

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, single-page-application, vue.js

I am having an issue with redirect rules for a single-page app that is on a sub-page of a Wordpress site. I have followed this set of instructions pretty directly and am still having issues: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193479/redirect-sub-pages-to-parent-without-changing-url

The subpages are custom post types for business locations. When someone visits `http://business.com/hollywood-ca/contact` it should pull up `http://business.com/hollywood-ca/` but the url needs to remain the same (The contact portion of the URL is part of a single-page Vue.js app on each location page, so it needs to stick around). Here is my code:

```
//This function hooks in on post save
function add_location_deep_links( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

  $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

  if ( "location" != $post_type ) return; // If this isn't a 'location' post, don't update it.

  $slug = $post->post_name; //hollywood-ca

  add_rewrite_rule(
    "^{$slug}/[A-Za-z]",  //regex prevents trying to redirect the /hollywood-ca/ page
    "index.php?page_id={$post_id}", //redirect to post
    'top' // take precedence over other redirects
  );

  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

The problem is when I visit `http://business.com/hollywood-ca/contact` the page redirects to `http://business.com/hollywood-ca/` which prevents my single-page app from navigating to the contact tab.

If it helps, I have also written a couple of functions that change my URLs from `business.com/location/hollywood-ca` to the cleaner `business.com/hollywood-ca`. I have tested these issues without those functions and am still having issues, so I don't think they are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer on Wordpress Exchange.  I needed to query `index.php` with the custom query variable for my custom post type instead of `page_id`:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    "^{$slug}/",  
    "index.php?location={$slug}", //changed query var to location
    'top'
);
```